# How to mock http request of a module or a module

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, automated-tests, mocha.js

I am using a module for sending email. (I did not created this module).

I want to test my app with the module. But I don't want to send email each time I test, so I thought to use this:
https://github.com/assaf/node-replay

(This let you fake http request, and record the answer for later).

Now the question. I a am forcing the email module to use node-reply, instead of regular requests methods.

I don't want to change the email module.

Is it possibile?

Comment: Do you have the link of the module for sending email?

Comment: There are many  models. It just an example